# how to create login api using odoo-node?

Tags: node.js, express, odoo, postgresql-9.3, odoo-9

I simply want to create api for login . no signup is there, username and password is already there in database.
simply want to get username and password from front end and , i have to check with existing database, whether username and password matching, then i have to send some success message or token, what ever it be.

font end side is angularjs. and in angularjs im using

```
  $http.post("/api address",usedata).success(data,success){}
```

like that but i have no idea how to do it in backend side. anyone please help.....

what i have tried with oddo is given below.

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
 var fs = require("fs");
 var Odoo = require('node-odoo');

var odoo = new Odoo({
  host: '192.168.1.121',
  port: 8091,
  database: 'oaveg_demo',
  username: 'dkashyap@oaveg.com',
  password: 'abcd@1234'
   });

 app.get('/api/userdetails',function(req, res) {
   odoo.connect(function(err) {
if (err) {
  return console.log(err);
}

  odoo.get('res.users', 14, function(err, partner) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }

    var userData = {};
    userData.name = partner.display_name;
    userData.email = partner.email;
    userData.id = partner.id;
    userData.password = partner.password;

    console.log('PARTNER GET====> ', userData);
  });

      var params = [['login','=','aritha@oaveg.com'],['password' , '=' , '']];

     odoo.search('res.users', params, function(err, partner) {
     if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
      }
      console.log('PARTNER SEARCH===> ', partner);
      })
    });

        });

        app.listen(3001);
```

Comment: You should be passing the login credentials from the front end to the backup and pulling off of the request object, instead of of hard coding username / password like you are.

Comment: Play around with the parameters in `app.get('/api/userdetails',function(req, res)`. You can log `req` and see what sort of information is coming across and pass it through your `odoo.connect` function as needed.